# ¿Cómo ver todas las clases css que están dentro de un elemento inspeccionado en el navegador? PD: Sólo de ese elemento

Tags: css, css3, consola, navegador-web

Estoy inspeccionando un elemento (slide), pero no sé cuales son las clases que realmente se están ejecutando de todo lo que tiene ese elemento, ni el orden en que van, alguna solución?... gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que posicionar el ratón encima del elemento, luego click derecho `inspeccionar el elemento` luego te saldrá resaltado el elemento en que deseas ver, saldrá algo como esto:

[image: imagen consola]

Mas a la derecha te saldran las clases que tiene aplicado el elemento:
[image: captura 2]

Un saludo!

Comment: Sí, me salen sólo la de ese elemento, junto con otras del resto de la página
El punto es que necesito saber no sólo las del elemento que inspecciono, sino de todos los elementos que hay dentro de ese elemento que inspecciono, por ej. tengo 3 divs dentro de otro div, al yo necesito saber las clases css de esos 4 divs, no sólo del div padre. Gracias.

Comment: Tu unica opcion es irte a los estilos de cada bloque por separado o inspeccionar el archivo fuente

Comment: Inspeccionar cada línea de código para ver sus respectivas clases css sería eterno, es un slide con demasiados elementos.
Y el código fuente css es un archivo minificado que tiene los estilos de toda la página, entonces no sé como encontrar específicamente los que funcionan solamente para el slide. Gracias.